# Storyboard missing constraint every time restart Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Using `auto layout` in `storyboard`,  I add some constraints on a `UILabel` and no warnings, then I restart `Xcode` it would show me the warning like the picture, I fixed the warning, but when I restart `Xcode` the same warning appears again.
Now there are about 20 same warnings in my `storyboard`, I have to fix it every time I restart `Xcode`.

### Edit for detail

```
1. A UILabel with width is 0 and constraints is like this
```

[image]

```
2. When I restart Xcode, then it change to :
```

[image]

```
3. And show me the warning:
```

[image]

```
4. Then I have to click the waring button and 'Update Frame' to fix it
```

[image]

Comment: Probably not helpfull, but this was one of the reasons I stopped using storyboard. With some math, I find it much easyer to create my UI in the ViewController. :)

Comment: You are talking about the UILabel, but on picture I see UITableView. You should provide more concrete example and additional information like wether or not you use size classes, what additional constraints involved, storyboard screenshots(!) etc. One important question is what do you see opening storyboard _on storyboard_ (not on navigator on the left): misplaced views or just warnings?

Comment: Try deleting your derived data.

Comment: I also encountered this problem. Every time I open Xcode, some views are miss displaced. However, it won't affect anything, So just ignore this warning.

Comment: @Danyun right it really wont't affect anything but it is troublesome .

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok Please have a look at the detail I appended thank you.

Comment: delete your tableview constraint and again add it newly and check??

Comment: @HussainShabbir Please ignore the first picture, the focus problem is on UILabels, and I tried delete and add one again, the problem still exist.

Comment: ok can you share your code??

Comment: @HussainShabbir sure I can, but I don't think there is any relation with code, cause it happens even the UILabel does not connected to any controller.

Comment: I meant your xib file in the code

Comment: I suspect you have copy pasted few xibs with same warning and didnt fix the issue in any xib.The problem is once you have missing constraints or overlapping constraints you will face this kind of issues.If you fix that issue partially without adding clear and proper constraints you will definitely have to with the constraints mismatch.Finally you only need to do something.If you have any views overlapping with improper frames you have to set from scratch.Any doubts???

Comment: Using XCODE Version 6.4 (6E35b) and I still have to update frames for more than 20 view every time i re-open my project...

Comment: Have the same issue!

Comment: It's almost been a year. WTF is Apple doing? Anytime I want to change something I have to spend 10 minutes fixing everything first...

Comment: Happening on Xcode 7.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a simple research I found that this bug could easily be reproduced and doesn't depends on git, storyboard permissions etc. To reproduce it you could just create UILabel without text and set its width to 0. Moreover you don't need to add some additional views, just only one UILabel. To conclude, I think you've found a bug in storyboard, and unfortunately I haven't found any workaround. Probably you should report it https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Yes I found all warnings appear on the UILabel without text and width(or height) is 0, agree with you.

Comment: Now I fix it by making all labels with default text, and report a bug to apple.

Comment: I am facing this same issue in Xcode 7.2 and i can also see that if there is UILable with text then the warning still appears and i have to change frames of each controls.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permissions issue on the Storyboard file that prevents your changes from being saved. Are other changes to the storyboard saved after you exit and reopen Xcode?

You can check the permission on Main.storyboard from Terminal by changing the directory to that of your app + /Base.lproj/

```
cd ~/Documents/YOUR_APP_CONTAINING_FOLDER/YOUR_APP_NAME/Base.lproj/
```

and using the command

```
ls -l
```

The outputted permissions on Main.storyboard should be -rw-r--r--

If the permissions are normal, does this issue only effect the auto layout constraints of UILabels or all UIElements?

Comment: yes it only effect the auto layout constraints of UILabels. and these labels's height is 0 or width is 0 cause their height or width are depend on text.

Comment: @Geaka, if so, the answer depends on wether or not you want label to be stretched according to text. Please provide screenshot of your storyboard and explain expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix it, make a git commit to the repo and then try to restart it. It will probably work if you use a VCS

Comment: Not works, and I don't think it is the problem of git.

Answer (score 0):

When using autolayout a lot of automatic routines are running. When they find an error in the constraints/views they try to fix it, by ignoring 'error' constraints. You see this that these 'error' constraints are not saved.

So when you make them again, you are creating constraints which are immediately labelled as faulty. So nog saved.

Comment: They are 'warnings' not 'errors', and they do not effect anything, looks like not saved, so how to save?

Comment: In Xcode a warning is almost always important. You shall not ignore them. And since autolayout takes actions based on these faulty constraints they are not saved. So as long as you are making invalid constraints they will not be saved!

Answer (score 0):

The issue does not look like your UILabel and tableView, but it happens due to the containerView which holds your both object. So try to set the constraint on your containerView. If it works then automatically your warning will be removed off.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue, but in our case we had one image that has been constantly deleting. What we did to fix this - we ensured we have the latest version in the Git, deleted the project from the local maschine and then cloned the Git repo once again. After that everything was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue solved in XCode Version 6.2 bate4 (6C107a).

XCode Version 6.2 bate4
Released: Jan 12, 2015
Build: 6C107a

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue on Xcode 6.3. I need update the constraint every time restart machine